# Filling empty lists with new input, instead of appending it

Tags: python

So right now I have this program:

```
def add(word_set, word):
    llist = word_set
    if len(llist) ==2:
        node = llist
        while node[1] != None:
            node = node[1]
        node[1] = [word,None]
    else:
        llist = [word,None]
    if llist not in word_set:
        word_set.append(llist)
```

word_list is just 10 empty lists, like so: `[][][][][][][][][][]`
Right now what my program does it add the lists filled with `[word,None]` at the end of the 10 empty lists. What I really want it to do is fill the empty lists.

For example, this is my output now if I print word_set:

```
[[][][][][][][][][][][word,None][word,None][word,None][word,None][word,None][word,None]]
```

What I want my output to be:

```
[word,None][word,None][word,None][word,None][word,None][word,None]]
```

For more information the function is getting called like this:

```
names = ["Ella", "Owen", "Fred", "Zoe", "Adam", "Ceve", "Adam", "Ceve", "Jonas", "Ola", "Morgan", "Fredrik", "Simon", "Albin", "Måns", "Amer", "David"]
for s in names:
    ws.add(word_set,s)
```

so instead of `word_set.append(llist)` at the end of the cycle I want

```
word_set[the next empty element] = llist
```

Edit: I forgot to tell you that I can only change the function, not what is it main.py

Comment: why are there 16 names, I thought the word list has always 10 entries? And if the word list does not have always 10 entries, why not start with an empty list and append to that.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I will make the list double in size everytime it gets filled. But I will work on the basics of filling the lists first.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of append you also can use `+=` which adds the new list to the existing one. Be aware of the list in list [[]] format.

```
def add(word_set, word):
    word_set += [[word, None]]
    return word_set

names = ["Ella", "Owen", "Fred", "Zoe", "Adam", "Ceve", "Adam", "Ceve", "Jonas", "Ola", "Morgan", "Fredrik", "Simon", "Albin", "Måns", "Amer", "David"]
word_set = []
for s in names:
    word_set = add(word_set,s)

print(word_set)
```

---

```
Out[8]: 
[['Ella', None],
 ['Owen', None],
 ['Fred', None],
 ['Zoe', None],
 ['Adam', None],
 ['Ceve', None],
 ['Adam', None],
 ['Ceve', None],
 ['Jonas', None],
 ['Ola', None],
 ['Morgan', None],
 ['Fredrik', None],
 ['Simon', None],
 ['Albin', None],
 ['Måns', None],
 ['Amer', None],
 ['David', None]]
```

Comment: I forgot to tell you that the only part I can change is the function. The only thing I can have in main is: for s in names: and the names.

Answer (score 0):

Find the first empty list with `word_set.index([])`

```
def add(word_set, word):
    item = [word, None]
    if item not in word_set:
        try:
            index = word_set.index([])
            word_set[index] = item
        except ValueError:
            print("list full")
```